# Git is not adding some files

Tags: git

I am using git to version control user-configuration files on my Linux home PC.

Git refuses to add these two files to the user-configuration repository:

```
~/.emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks
~/.emacs.d/.cache/recentf
```

Directory .emacs.d/ contains a .git repository.
All files outside of .emacs.d/ where added without issue.

Is there a way to track the two files as if they where not in another git repository?
Git submodule seems like over kill.

I am running git version 2.33.1 on Fedora 35 Workstation.

Here are some other things that might be relevant:

gitc alias is defined in my .bashrc file:

```
alias gitc='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/config_repo --work-tree=$HOME'
```

Git add executes and returns silently but nothing is added:

```
$ gitc add .emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks .emacs.d/.cache/recentf
$ gitc status
On branch clean_install_orphan
nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)
```

The .emacs.d/.cache/ files are not listed in the tracked committed files:

```
$ gitc ls-files .emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks .emacs.d/.cache/recentf
```

returns nothing.

After editing the .emacs.d/.cache/recentf file, it is not listed in:

```
$ gitc status
```

because it was never added.

Add force option gets similar results:

```
$ gitc add -f .emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks .emacs.d/.cache/recentf
```

The files exists and the paths are correct:

```
$ cd ~
$ ls -l .emacs.d/.cache/recentf
-rw-------. 1 wolfv wolfv 2999 Jan 11 00:41 .emacs.d/.cache/recentf
$ ls -l .emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks
-rw-r--r--. 1 wolfv wolfv 1663 Jan  2 10:39 .emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks
```

There is no .gitignore or .gitignore_global file in HOME.

The repository's exclude file is empty:

```
$ more config_repo/info/exclude
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
```

The --bare option was used when initializing the repository:

```
$ git init --bare $HOME/config_repo
```

which should not cause the problem.

.cache is not a symlink:

```
$ ls -la .emacs.d/
..
drwxr-xr-x. 1 wolfv wolfv    452 Jan 11 00:41 .cache
..
```

Comment: The top of your question refers to `.cached` but the rest refers to `.cache`: presumably one of these is a typo; I'll assume the first one is. Apart from that: is `.cache` an ordinary directory, or is it a symlink? Is there any `.gitignore` in effect? (Probably not or the `add -f` would override it.)

Comment: As a side note, Git is fine for maintaining config files, but is not very good as an actual backup system. You might find that you don't need to back up Git-maintained files once you have the repository itself replicated, but in general I find it best to do both things (backups *and* repositories, i.e., the belt-and-suspenders / belt-and-braces approach).

Comment: @torek, .cache/ is not a symlink.  Yes, 'cached' was a typo.  Thanks.  There is no .gitignore or .gitignore_global file in HOME.
I backup the repository.  Is that safe?

Comment: Backing up the repository (with system backup tools) *should* be safe. Keeping a clone elsewhere is convenient (easier than backup tools) and useful for most accidents. Just remember the idea of diversity, you don't want (eg) a fire to destroy both the computer and all the backups that are in the same location as the computer. :-) (and I just re-read the question and know the problem, I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that:

> Directory `.emacs.d/` contains a `.git` repository.

This is the problem.  Git will refuse to store a Git repository within a Git repository.  This is for a number of good reasons.  You can in theory sort of work around it by renaming the `.git` to, e.g., `.got` and then adding that, but don't do that.

If you attempt to `git add` a Git repository to another Git repository, the "outer" repository will wind up containing a *reference to* (not a copy of) the inner repository.  Internally, this reference takes the form of a thing Git calls a *gitlink*.  The gitlink is a crucial part of a Git *submodule*, but is not all of a submodule: for a submodule to "work right", there's a second crucial part that Git stores in `.gitmodules`.  The `git add` command will create or update a gitlink, but will not create the correct `.gitmodules` file.

You can either:

- stop using a *separate* Git repository within `.emacs.d`, or
- just treat this as two repositories (with or without treating `.emacs.d` as a submodule) and back up and/or replicate both Git repositories.

To treat `.emacs.d` as a submodule, use `git submodule add` at least once to create the `.gitmodules` file in the superior (or *superproject* ) repository whose database resides in `--git-dir=$HOME/config_repo`.  In this case that would be `gitc submodule add`, which probably works, but I don't know if the potential interaction issues with `--git-dir` arguments vs submodules (which themselves use `--git-dir` internally) are normally tested when Git is built.  To avoid using it as a submodule, just carry on as you are doing already and *do not* `gitc add .emacs.d`.

Comment: From https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs?at=61e00191742c3d4b2195daa7 :  Your ~/emacs.d/.git/ directory contains the Spacemacs data and history managed by Git. This is what allows you to fetch newer changes using Git. If you don't need to make upgrades using Git, you can simply delete the /.git/ subdirectory. Otherwise you may want to either copy the bookmarks for backup elsewhere, or commit them to your private branch in the Spacemacs Git repo and add it to your configuration as a git submodule.

Comment: I renamed ~/.emacs.d/.git to ~/.emacs.d/.git_orig.  Then add with force option because ~/.emacs.d contains a .gitignore: gitc add -f .emacs.d/.cache/bookmarks .emacs.d/.cache/recentf

Comment: OK - there you go. I will note that if there's a `.gitignore` there, perhaps they think that these files should never be saved (including in backups?). A `cache` directory is often just there to optimize things, e.g., browsers will cache downloaded files but there's (usually) no point saving them in backups since you can just revisit the site to reload the files. On the other hand, since backups serve a different *purpose*, I might want cache files backed up. :-)

Comment: .cache/recentf changes all the time and only gets saved before clean OS install.  .cache/bookmarks is version controlled like the other config files.  Everything works as intended :)